# Django redirect another view from another app form

Tags: django, django-views

contact/views.py

```
from django.core.mail import send_mail, BadHeaderError
from django.http import HttpResponse, HttpResponseRedirect
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from .forms import ContactForm

def contactView(request):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        form = ContactForm()
    else:
        form = ContactForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            subject = form.cleaned_data['subject']
            from_email = form.cleaned_data['from_email']
            message = form.cleaned_data['message']
            try:
                send_mail(subject, message, from_email, ['admin@example.com'])
            except BadHeaderError:
                return HttpResponse('Invalid header found.')
            # return redirect('success')
            return redirect('PostList') #another view from another app
    return render(request, "contact.html", {'form': form})

# def successView(request):
#     return HttpResponse('Success! Thank you for your message.')
```

contact/urls.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path

from .views import contactView

urlpatterns = [
    path('contact/', contactView, name='contact'),
    # path('success/', successView, name='success'),
]
```

blog/views.py

```
from django.views import generic
from .models import Post, PostImage


# Create your views here.

class PostList(generic.ListView):
    queryset = Post.objects.filter(status=1).order_by('-created_on')
    template_name = 'index.html'

class PostDetail(generic.DetailView):
    model = Post
    template_name = 'post_detail.html'
    
    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        # Call the base implementation first to get a context
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        # Add in a QuerySet of all the books
        # context['image_list'] = PostImage.objects.all()
        # context['image_list'] = self.get_object().postimage_set.all()

        context['image_list'] = PostImage.objects.filter(post__slug=self.kwargs.get('slug'))
        return context
```

blog/urls.py

```
from . import views
from django.urls import path

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.PostList.as_view(), name='home'),
    path('<slug:slug>/', views.PostDetail.as_view(), name='post_detail'),
]
```

I need the following in the SIMPLEST DRY manner possible; how do I write this redirect inside `contact/views.py`?

`return redirect('PostList') #another view from another app`

`PostList` is a class-based view from another app called blog. It is the homepage essentially.

for reference..
https://ordinarycoders.com/blog/article/django-messages-framework

Answer (score 1):

In your project folder (eg, my_project/my_project) you should have a urls.py with something like this

```
path("admin/", admin.site.urls),
path("", include("blog.urls")),
path("", include("contact.urls"))
```

This allows django to look through all url files in the order listed.  So long as all your url names and patterns are unique, then your view should be able to simply do

```
from django.shortcuts import redirect
from django.urls import reverse

return redirect(reverse('home'))
```

'home' being the name value of the ListView.

(NB: if you have  various applevel urls.py files with `path(''`...  django will take the first one it hits)